# how can find x and y from equation x+y x*y

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy, equation

I have this code in python3, I use sympy and I would like to know how I can find x and y. Do you have any ideas?

```
  x, y = symbols ('x, y')
  eq1 = (x + y) / threshold - 1
  eq2 = (x * y) / key.n - 1
  sol = solve ((eq1, eq2), (x, y))
```

Comment: What did you get for `sol`?

Comment: You could use x+y,x*y to be elementary symmetrical functions, and [build a poly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) using them,and then find the roots of that poly. But maybe `solve` already tries that

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SymPy documentations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html), there are many examples that might suit you.

Note that the equations in `solve()` refer to equality at 0, so in your case the two equation are:

- x+y = 0
- x*y = 0

so the solution is x = -y.